# Область видимости файла

Tags: java

Я помещаю файл `test.txt` в туже директорию, что и метод `main`. В методе `main` пишу следующее:

```
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("test.txt"));
```

В ответ получаю:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: test.txt (Нет такого файла или каталога)
```

Основной класс из которого я запускаю приложение находится в директории `src/decorator/inputStreamExample/`. `test.txt` там же.

Что я делаю не так ?

Comment: Как Вы запускаете программу? Какой у процесса текущий/рабочий директорий?

Comment: Я недостаточно хорошо ориентируюсь в терминах языка Java. Что значит "в туже директорию, что и метод main"? В директориях находятся файлы, а не методы. Что значит "класс из которого я запускаю". Программа запускается из класса? Объясните кто-нибудь, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Igor а разве в C# программа запускается не из статического метода main ?

Comment: Я тоже люблю отвечать вопросом на вопрос :). Нет, в C# статический `Main` является частью программы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я пробовал твой код загружать в idea, но там и правда ошибки есть.
Вот отредактированный вариант:

```
public class FileOpen {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("src/java/Text.txt"));
        System.out.println(in.available());
    }
}
```

У тебя ошибки с путем файла.
Попробуй "src/decorator/inputStreamExample/test.txt". И еще, смотри, где у  тебя стоит маркировка source. Сейчас проверил: если маркировка на src и потом там создать пакет, в нем еще один и там уже класс с текстовым файлом, то так же будут ошибки. Если же в src создать один пакет, в нем класс с файлом, то все нормально ищется.

Comment: Ваш код не работает.Конструктор FileInputStream ожидает как переменную типа File, так и String так и FileDescriptor, это тут ни причём. Кроме того, вы создаете новый файл, вместо того, что бы читать из уже существующего, как это задумано автором.

Comment: @RostykShevtsiv я не создаю новый файл здесь "File file = new File("Text.txt");" посмотрите конструктор класса File.

Comment: Обновил ответ. Критикуйте...

Comment: извиняюсь, я имел в виду определяете файл, который в это не нуждается.

Comment: @RostykShevtsiv так ты в комментарии все сказал, я отредактировал ответ, дополнил еще, а теперь верный ответ, с минусом. Но спасибо зак конструктивную критику.

Comment: После обновления ответа результат не изменился.Код по прежнему не работает, так как было сказано поместить его в пакет с main-классом, а вы почему-то создали его в папке src(вне пакета).

Comment: @RostykShevtsiv это все придирки, обновил ответ. Теперь файл "Text.txt" расположен в папке с классом, это все семантика. Я человеку помог надеюсь. Спасибо за "дискуссию".

Comment: Во-первых, вы редактируете сообщение настолько часто что я не успеваю комментировать, а во-вторых, даже изменённый вариант не работает.Я не понимаю, зачем вы советуете людям то, что сами не тестировали?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45062/discussion-between-rostyk-shevtsiv-and-bangerok).

Answer (score 1):

Вам стоит использовать следующую конструкцию: `InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(ClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("test.txt"));`Где ClassName - имя вашего класса.